# Best approximation of MSE of a list of numbers with piecewise constant list with at most one discontinuity

Tags: optimization

*This is kind of a programming question, but it feels too stats-y for StackOverflow. Happy to move it if others disagree.*

---

I was asked this during an interview a while ago. The first question is:

> Input is a sorted list of numbers, for example, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13]`. Can you give me one constant `c` that best approximates the list under the mean squared error, i.e. `argmin sum (c - x_i)^2`?

This part is easy. The answer is just the mean, which minimizes the MSE. But then he asked:

> What if I allow you a piecewise constant list with at most one discontinuity? For example, one valid approximator could be `[0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]`.

My attempt was to consider all possible slices of the input array `x`, and simply take the mean of each half:

```py
def piecewise_mse(x):
    n       = len(x)
    min_mse = np.inf
    guess   = None
    for i in range(1, n):
        a = x[:i]
        b = x[i:]
        c = np.append(np.ones(i)   * np.mean(a),
                      np.ones(n-i) * np.mean(b))
        mse = np.sum((x - c)**2)
        if mse < min_mse:
            min_mse = mse
            guess = c
    return guess
```

So the best piecewise constant list with at most one discontinuity for the example list is

```
[ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3. 12. 12. 12.]
```

I was told that this approach would work, but I have two questions.

1. Is this the optimal approach? If my approach is optimal, is there a good argument for why? I'm a bit bothered by the fact that he said "at most one discontinuity", since perhaps I'm missing a good reason there should be no discontinuities.
2. My interviewer said that this could be done in `O(N)` time, where `N = len(x)`. I'm not quite sure how to do this, although he suggested to think about the variance. My guess is that I would need to keep running sums of `E[X^2]` and `E[X]^2`.